# How to add the condition that there is a minimum amount of data to calculate a variable in `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

I have two dataframes. The first one `df` summarises detections of several individuals (`ID`) of a fish species overtime (`DateTime`). As an example:

```
options("digits.secs" = 3)

df<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2017-08-05 14:03:55.300","2017-08-05 16:18:12.100","2017-08-05 20:34:31.540","2017-08-05 16:18:14.355","2017-08-05 20:34:33.605"),
    ID= c("A","B","C","B","C"))

df
                 DateTime ID
1 2017-08-05 14:03:55.300  A
2 2017-08-05 16:18:12.100  B
3 2017-08-05 20:34:31.540  C
4 2017-08-05 16:18:14.355  B
5 2017-08-05 20:34:33.605  C
```

The other dataframe `Activity` has activity info about those individuals over time. This data is at high temporal resolution. That is, it is 11 data per second (11 hertz). As a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(100)
fmt <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 14:03:55.100", format=fmt, tz="UTC"), by=1/11, length.out=80)
ID = rep("A", each=80)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 80, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 80, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 80, replace = TRUE)
Activity1<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 16:18:11.900", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/5, length.out=40)
ID = rep("B", each=40)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 40, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 40, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 40, replace = TRUE)
Activity2<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 16:18:19.703", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/11, length.out=40)
ID = rep("B", each=40)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 40, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 40, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 40, replace = TRUE)
Activity3<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 20:34:31.240", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/11, length.out=80)
ID = rep("C", each=80)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 80, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 80, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 80, replace = TRUE)
Activity4<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)
Activity<- rbind(Activity1,Activity2,Activity3,Activity4)

head(Activity)
                 DateTime ID     x     y     z
1 2017-08-05 14:03:55.099  A  0.01 -0.16 -1.00
2 2017-08-05 14:03:55.190  A  0.11  0.55 -0.69
3 2017-08-05 14:03:55.281  A  0.50  0.79  1.00
4 2017-08-05 14:03:55.372  A  0.97 -0.76  0.24
5 2017-08-05 14:03:55.463  A -0.97 -0.59  0.20
6 2017-08-05 14:03:55.554  A -0.46  0.42 -0.88
```

I am using the code below to calculate the variables `VeDBA` and `RMS` in `df`. I use data from `Activity` to calculate them, and I add those variables to the dataframe `df`. As a summary, for each row of `df` data, I calculate `VeDBA` and `RMS` using 2 seconds of data (which is 22 rows since I have 11 data per second in the dataframe `Activity`) from the `Activity` data frame and using the `DateTime` of the data frame  `df` as the start time.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime, format=fmt, tz="UTC")][,
    c("start", "end") := .(DateTime, DateTime+2)]
setDT(Activity)[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime, format=fmt, tz="UTC")]

df<- Activity[df, on=.(ID, DateTime>=start, DateTime<=end),
    by=.EACHI, .(
        DateTime=i.DateTime,
        ID=i.ID, 
        VeDBA=sum(sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)) / .N,
        RMS=sqrt((sum(x^2) + sum(y^2) + sum(z^2)) / .N))][, 
            (1L:3L) := NULL][]
```

The problem is that sometimes I have 5 data per second instead of 11 in the dataframe `Activity`. So I want to include some kind of code that indicates than, for instance, when I have less than 14 data in the mentioned 2 second period, I want to appear `NA` for `VeDBA` and `RMS` in `df`.

With the mentioned code I get this so far:

```
df
                  DateTime ID     VeDBA       RMS
1: 2017-08-05 14:03:55.299  A 0.9919576 1.0264458
2: 2017-08-05 16:18:12.099  B 0.9375138 0.9573975
3: 2017-08-05 20:34:31.539  C 0.9294209 0.9764383
4: 2017-08-05 16:18:14.355  B 0.7542922 0.7886634
5: 2017-08-05 20:34:33.605  C 1.0041628 1.0395891
```

And I would like to get this:

```
df
                  DateTime ID     VeDBA       RMS
1: 2017-08-05 14:03:55.299  A 0.9919576 1.0264458
2: 2017-08-05 16:18:12.099  B NA        NA        # Between 16:18:12.099 and 16:18:14.099 there is only 10 data instead of 22
3: 2017-08-05 20:34:31.539  C 0.9294209 0.9764383
4: 2017-08-05 16:18:14.355  B NA        NA
5: 2017-08-05 20:34:33.605  C 1.0041628 1.0395891
```

Does anyone know how to modify the code I am using with `data.table` to get those `NAs`?

Comment: I'm away from my computer at the time, but it seems you can get a boost from `rle` and/or `data.table::rleid`

Comment: Hi @PavoDive. I don't know exactly what you mean. I haven't used too much `data.table`. I would appreciate if you can specify how I can do what I explained in the post.... Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modification below returns `NA` if `.N` is below the given threshhold `n_min`:

```
n_min <- 14L
Activity[df, on = .(ID, DateTime >= start, DateTime <= end),
         by = .EACHI, .(
           DateTime = i.DateTime,
           ID = i.ID,
           .N,  # inserted just to verify the result, to be omitted in production code
           VeDBA = if (.N < n_min) NA_real_ else sum(sqrt(x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 + z ^ 2)) / .N,
           RMS = if (.N < n_min) NA_real_ else sqrt((sum(x ^ 2) + sum(y ^ 2) + sum(z ^ 2)) / .N)
         )][,
            (1L:3L) := NULL][]
```

> ```
>                   DateTime ID  N     VeDBA       RMS
> 1: 2017-08-05 14:03:55.299  A 22 0.8777660 0.9181305
> 2: 2017-08-05 16:18:12.099  B 10        NA        NA
> 3: 2017-08-05 20:34:31.539  C 22 0.8807835 0.9383084
> 4: 2017-08-05 16:18:14.355  B 10        NA        NA
> 5: 2017-08-05 20:34:33.605  C 22 1.0587765 1.1023549
> ```

Please, note that column `N` has been inserted just to verify the result. Also note that the output differs from OP's expected result although `set.seed(100)` was used to create the data.

`if()` can be used here because there is only one `.N` value per `.EACHI` group.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe!! I get the error message `unused arguments` when I run your code. I guess this is because `NA_real_` isn't defined in your code, isn't it? If not, what could it be?

Comment: While waiting for your answer I ask you other doubts. Regarding your results and mine are different, I was wrong about the `NA` since 4th row should have `NA` for `VeDBA` and `RMS` (I have modified that in my post). Regarding the differences in the values for `VeDBA` and `RMS` I gues it is because your dataframe `Activity` and mine are different even after using `set.seed()`. Some days ago I found out that if your R version is below 3.16, then `sample()` produces different numbers... To verify that, I showed the head of my `Activity` dataframe in the post. Do you have the same numbers?

Comment: I have seen this error message if one of the data frames involved is *not* a data.table object.

Comment: I found the problem @Uwe. Exactly, you didn't add in your code the transformation from data.frame to data.table and I didn't realized. If I run `setDT(df)[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime, format=fmt, tz="UTC")][,
    c("start", "end") := .(DateTime, DateTime+2)]` and `setDT(Activity)[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime, format=fmt, tz="UTC")]` before your code, then it works perfectly. Thanks again!!

Comment: I am sorry for having caused a misunderstanding. I didn't post the whole code but only the part which needs to be amended. Concerning `set.seed()` on different R versions: I using RStudio Cloud and `sessionInfo()` says it's R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26), 
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit),
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, ..., Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding. Unfortunately, I am getting different figures running your start-up code. What does `sessionInfo()` return for you?

Comment: No problem! Thanks @Uwe. My `sessionInfo()` says it is 3.6.2 (2019-12-12), Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) and Running under: Ubuntu 19.04. I don't see info about `Random number generation...` Do I have to use a specific code to see that?